# ASP error: msxml3.dll error 80070005, access is denied. How do I set the correct permissions?

Tags: xml, xslt, iis, asp-classic

I am having some trouble with this in-browser form. I am learning how to edit XML in-browser with XSLT and ASP, following a tutorial. I installed IIS, and enabled the ASP features, but when I attempt to run my code, I receive this error:

> msxml3.dll error '80070005'
>
> Access is denied.
>
> /xmlEdit/edittool.asp, line 43

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like this is probably something to do with my permissions or settings in IIS, but I'm a newbie to setting up IIS and web testing environments. The code is from w3schools' exit XML tutorial.

tool.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tool>
  <field id="prodName">
    <value>HAMMER HG2606</value>
  </field>
  <field id="prodNo">
    <value>32456240</value>
  </field>
  <field id="price">
    <value>$30.00</value>
  </field>
</tool>
```

tool.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <form method="post" action="edittool.asp">
  <h2>Tool Information (edit):</h2>
  <table border="0">
    <xsl:for-each select="tool/field">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
      <td>
      <input type="text">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="value" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      </input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" id="btn_sub" name="btn_sub" value="Submit" />
  <input type="reset" id="btn_res" name="btn_res" value="Reset" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

tool_updated.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Updated Tool Information:</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="tool/field">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="value" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

edittool.asp:

```
<%
function loadFile(xmlfile,xslfile)
Dim xmlDoc,xslDoc
'Load XML and XSL file
set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async = false
xmlDoc.load(xmlfile)
set xslDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xslDoc.async = false
xslDoc.load(xslfile)
'Transform file
Response.Write(xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc))
end function

function updateFile(xmlfile)
Dim xmlDoc,rootEl,f
Dim i
'Load XML file
set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async = false
xmlDoc.load(xmlfile)

'Set the rootEl variable equal to the root element
Set rootEl = xmlDoc.documentElement

'Loop through the form collection
for i = 1 To Request.Form.Count
  'Eliminate button elements in the form
  if instr(1,Request.Form.Key(i),"btn_")=0 then
    'The selectSingleNode method queries the XML file for a single node
    'that matches a query. This query requests the value element that is
    'the child of a field element that has an id attribute which matches
    'the current key value in the Form Collection. When there is a match -
    'set the text property equal to the value of the current field in the
    'Form Collection.
    set f = rootEl.selectSingleNode("field[@id='" & _
    Request.Form.Key(i) & "']/value")
    f.Text = Request.Form(i)
  end if
next

'Save the modified XML file
xmlDoc.save xmlfile

'Release all object references
set xmlDoc=nothing
set rootEl=nothing
set f=nothing

'Load the modified XML file with a style sheet that
'allows the client to see the edited information
loadFile xmlfile,server.MapPath("tool_updated.xsl")
end function

'If form is submitted, update the XML file and display result
' - if not, transform the XML file for editing
if Request.Form("btn_sub")="" then
  loadFile server.MapPath("tool.xml"),server.MapPath("tool.xsl")
else
  updateFile server.MapPath("tool.xml")
end if
%>
```

Comment: Side note: unless you have very good reason to learn 20 years old technology consider newer alternatives. ASP.Net may be easier to get samples/help...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov - the technology may be 20 years old but it is still preferred over PHP by those who are familiar with it,  and especially over ASP.Net which only complicates things to the nth degree.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem. Try adding this at the top of your classic ASP page:

```
<% On Error Resume Next %>
```

There seems to be a bug with Microsoft's component where it throws the error even though it actually works.  By throwing the error, it halts your page from processing.  By ignoring the error, it works fine.

Comment: <% On Error Resume Next %>

Comment: In a post, indent your code with four spaces to format it as such and display it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Line 43 is

```
xmlDoc.save xmlfile
```

The error message suggests that your IUSR account doesn't have write permission on your xml file, which I assume is tool.xml. Right click on it, select Properties and then click on the security tab and it should be obvious from there.

The W3Schools tutorial is old. I suggest you replace

```
Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
```

with

```
Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
```

This will call msxml6.dll - which is the most recent version of the processor